# Updating Numpy value in multiprocessing pool doesn't work

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

This program is not what I am working on but it's similar to what I want to achieve. I am trying to update numpy value but it does not work. Tried many steps but didn't work. Please help me out

```py
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing 
from random import random
import time
sparse_matrix = np.zeros((100,100))

def temp(x,y):
    global sparse_matrix
    sparse_matrix[x,y] = random()
    print(sparse_matrix)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

for x in range(0,99):
    for y in range(0,99):
        multiprocessing.Process(target=temp, args=(x,y,)).start()
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would say that `global sparse_matrix` is not working - in the ***other*** process's there is no reference to the array. Maybe establish a pipe to communicate between processes and have temp return a tuple - `(xcoord,ycoord,value)`.  I like using [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) myself - it has a nice interface.

Comment: Your description says multi*threading*, your code shows multi*processing*. Which do you actually want? Neither multithreading nor multiprocessing is suitable for per-task updates – what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: This is very confused code. You create a multiprocessing pool and then you don't use it. You iterate `x` and `y` using `range` but set these values in the loop, which have no real effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design the function to accept a row and column argument and return a `(row,column,value)` tuple; make a list of `(row,column)` tuples and use them with Pool.map.

```
import multiprocessing
from random import random

m,n = 3,3
sparse_matrix = np.zeros((m,n))

def f(*args):
    x,y,*_ = args[0]
    return (x,y,random())

coords = []
for x in range(m):
    for y in range(n):
        coords.append((x,y))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

    with pool as p:
        results = p.map(f,coords)
     
    for x,y,v in results:
        sparse_matrix[x,y] = v

    print(sparse_matrix)
```

---

```
m,n = 3,3
sparse_matrix = np.zeros((m,n))

def f(x,y):
    # print(x,y)
    return (x,y,random())

coords = []
for x in range(m):
    for y in range(n):
        coords.append((x,y))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

    with pool as p:
        results = p.starmap_async(f,coords)
        for x,y,v in results.get():
            sparse_matrix[x,y] = v

    print(sparse_matrix)
```

Comment: Any reason you used `starmap_async` rather than plain old `starmap` given that it's the one and only "job" being submitted to the pool?

Comment: I actually do not know how they are different. Every time I see that async_something in the multiprocessing module I get a funny look on my face.

Comment: @Booboo - If it is not an appropriate use case let me know..

Comment: `starmap_async` does not block but instead returns an `AsyncResult` instance on which you have to call `get` (which then blocks) to get the return value of the "job"). This is suitable if you want to submit multiple jobs, save all the `AsyncResult` objects and then wait for the jobs to complete and thus allowing multiple jobs to run in parallel. Plain old `results = `p.starmap(...)` is equivalent to `async_result = p.async_starmap(...); results = async_result.get()`, which us what you did and is just simpler if you have only one job to submit and wait for. What you did is not wrong, per se.

Comment: In other words, you could have just coded: `for x, y, v in p.starmap(f,coords):`

Comment: I understood that much about the AsyncResult blocking till all was done but haven't the imagination or run into a circumstance where I could say aha that is what those methods were meant for. Are you saying they are meant for multiple *different* tasks?

Comment: `In other words, ` - yes I played with it both ways.

Comment: Not necessarily. You could be submitting to the same worker function with different arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your ans. This method works but has the value of coords in our case is really big. It takes more than 800GB Ram. So pratically I can't use it due to high ram usage and initial wait time to append the data

Comment: @harsh_jain100 - did you try [BooBoo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66186360/2823755) answer?

Answer (score 2):

I know you have already accepted an answer, but I offer you this for your consideration:

You can in have your processing pool work directly on a `numpy` array and setting values within it instead of returning values back to the main process that then has to do the setting. Having the main process do the setting is fine for the very simple case you proposed but when the worker function is setting multiple values, this becomes unwieldly. The "trick" is to have the `numpy` array backed by a `multiprocessing.Array` instance that lives in shared memory:

```py
import numpy as np
import ctypes
import multiprocessing as mp
from random import random


def to_numpy_array(shared_array, shape):
    '''Create a numpy array backed by a shared memory Array.'''
    arr = np.ctypeslib.as_array(shared_array)
    return arr.reshape(shape)


def init_worker(shared_array, shape):
    '''
    Initialize worker for processing:
    Create the numpy array from the shared memory Array for each process in the pool.
    '''
    global arr
    arr = to_numpy_array(shared_array, shape)


def worker_fun(x, y):
    '''worker function'''
    arr[x, y] = random()


def main():
    nrows = 5
    ncols = 5
    shape = (nrows, ncols)

    shared_array = mp.Array(ctypes.c_double, nrows * ncols, lock=False)
    arr = to_numpy_array(shared_array, shape)
    print(arr)
    print('-' * 80)

    x_y_values = [(x, y) for x in range(nrows) for y in range(ncols)]

    pool = mp.Pool(initializer=init_worker, initargs=(shared_array, shape))
    pool.starmap(worker_fun, x_y_values)

    print(arr)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[[0.84368014 0.22247799 0.36832485 0.88236445 0.00937686]
 [0.56830305 0.11892319 0.62755203 0.24523884 0.27514482]
 [0.53711605 0.6173108  0.20190477 0.2480388  0.7353915 ]
 [0.82826334 0.418652   0.17796469 0.99261767 0.8693143 ]
 [0.25177398 0.65617204 0.6526661  0.4863473  0.33542287]]
```

**Update**

Instead of starting off with a shared memory `Array`, it is probably more natural to start with a `numpy` array and initialize a shared memory array from that. But in this case you will then have to re-initialize the `numpy` array to use the shared memory Array as its backing. We need to add function `to_shared_array`. I have also updated the `to_numpy_array` method that does not require a hard-coded `ctypes` value.

```py
def to_shared_array(arr, ctype):
    shared_array = mp.Array(ctype, arr.size, lock=False)
    temp = np.frombuffer(shared_array, dtype=arr.dtype)
    temp[:] = arr.flatten(order='C')
    return shared_array


def main():
    arr = np.zeros((5, 5))
    print(arr)
    print('-' * 80)
    shape = arr.shape
    shared_array = to_shared_array(arr, ctypes.c_double)
    # you have to now use the shared array as the base
    arr = to_numpy_array(shared_array, shape)
    x_y_values = [(x, y) for x in range(shape[0]) for y in range(shape[1])]
    pool = mp.Pool(initializer=init_worker, initargs=(shared_array, shape))
    pool.starmap(worker_fun, x_y_values)
    print(arr)
```

Comment: I've shied away from using any of the shared memory objects - for no other reason than lack of  use.

Comment: Yes, but the OP was looking for a solution where they could operate directly on, i.e. set values in, the `numpy` array,

Comment: I started with a shared memory array (just float zeros) and initialized a `numpy` array from it. But in more complicated cases, I could have started with a `numpy` array and then initialized a shared memory array from that. Maybe that would have been the better example.